# FormValidation Error as No provider for FormBuilder even after after adding ReactiveFormsModule

Tags: angular2-forms

I try to implement simple form validation im Getting error as  as No provider for FormBuilder  Even after i Added ReactiveFormsModule in mg NgModule

```
@Injectable()
export class Employeecomponent implements OnInit  {
    customerForm: FormGroup;
    currentCustomer: Employee = new Employee();
    EmpArray: Employee[];
    constructor(private _HttpService: EmployeeService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
```

This is my NgModule

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(EmployeeRouet),
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule],

    declarations: [Employeecomponent],
    bootstrap: [Employeecomponent],

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please try this importing,

```
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and adding `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` in `ngImport`.

mainly check your project structure if you have any module file rather than `app.module.ts` you need to mention same into that.